# Broadcast Receiver for permission change in settings

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Android M, if user manually changes the permission in settings for my app it always restarts my app and activity. This leads to abnormal behaviour in most of the screens.

Is there any broadcast receiver to know user has revoked/granted permission from settings? Or is there any other way to handle this restart behaviour?

Comment: I'm having problem that looks like yours, when I give a permission and I go back to the running app, the app continues open, if I go to seetings and remove the permission the app restarts

Comment: in my case app is not restarting.how to restart it?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a non-functional app - there are many reasons why Android might stop and restart the app, so if your app misbehaves when that happens, you need to fix your app.

The restart when permissions change is new in Marshmallow, and there is no way to opt out of that behaviour and be notified in a different way.